# Kiwi TCMS - Test Email failing

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm trying to setup SMTP for Kiwi TCMS. When trying to send a test email I'm getting a long error and at the bottom it says OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Here is the SMTP setup on the common.py file:

```
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'emailaddress'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = "[Kiwi-TCMS] "
```

```
#  SMTP specific settings
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'emailaddress'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

I have tried restarting the container and recreating the container